# Unable to change nav menu font color

Tags: css, fonts, menu, colors, nav

I am obviously making a silly error. Please can you help me spot it.
Using Bootstrap. I want a simple nav menu and it is working BUT I simply can't manage to change the color of the font.
Here is the code I have used.

```
.nav li {
  color: red
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background: white;
  }
.nav li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    }
```

Here is the HTML

```
 <div class="nav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" >
<li><a href="About.htm">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="HoP.htm">HOME of PEACE</a></li>
<li><a href="update.htm">NEWS UPDATE</a></li> 
<li><a href="Pastnews.htm">PREVIOUS NEWSLETER</a></li> 
<li><a href="Sponsor.htm">SUPPORT the WORK</a></li> 
<li><a href="giftaid.htm">GIFT AID</a></li> 
<li><a href="Contact.htm">CONTACT</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Apply color to `.nav li a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply color on `.nav a` like this

```css
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background: white
  }
.nav a {
    color: red
    }
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" >
<li><a href="About.htm">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="HoP.htm">HOME of PEACE</a></li>
<li><a href="update.htm">NEWS UPDATE</a></li> 
<li><a href="Pastnews.htm">PREVIOUS NEWSLETER</a></li> 
<li><a href="Sponsor.htm">SUPPORT the WORK</a></li> 
<li><a href="giftaid.htm">GIFT AID</a></li> 
<li><a href="Contact.htm">CONTACT</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls add this css

```
.nav li a {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background: white;
  }
.nav li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: better use `.nav a` in this case you don't need `.nav li a `.

Comment: Tambo and WisdmLab thank you. You solved my problem. Mucg appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add semicolon after `"color: red"` i.e. `"color: red; "`.